# En Postgresql Como importo una tabla csv sin necesidad de crear columnas en el Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, csv, tablas, headers

Quiero importar datos de una tabla csv al Postgresql, pero no quiero tener que crear las columnas en el Postgresql, porque son muchas. Quiero que al importar la tabla me reconozca cuales son los encabezados e importe los datos que contiene el csv

Gracias

Comment: Te planteo lo siguiente: Un csv no guarda en si mismo los tipos de las columnas. ¿Cómo haría postgresql para entender de que tipo es la columna? Por ejemplo, si en el csv aparece 10, podría tratarse tanto de un número como una cadena. E incluso sabiendo el tipo, quedan otras dudas: "¿Cuál es el largo?" "¿Cual es la presición?" "¿Cuantos decimales tiene?" "¿Cuál es el formato de la fecha?".

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @dante-s,  eso puede ser dificil de lograr, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083588/8308381) hay un ejemplo de como pudieras lograrlo , pero tendrias luego que hacer todas modificaciones de los tipos de datos y nombres de columas y puedo ser lento ese proceso de casteo, pero exitos